# TreeView component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, treeview, vue-component

I trying to create `tree view` component (something like this https://www.jstree.com/), where I can turn on `edit mode` and select which one should be visible. I tried different ways, but none of them worked properly. I would like to have access to selected tree and entire tree from outer component, so it probably should be reactive.

It's not reactive, because of nested arrays (children).

How to reproduce:

1. Click `Edit` in left tree
2. Click `Expand all` on both tree
3. Click some
   nested checkboxes

Right tree view should changed, but it doesn't.

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rs3hoktb/

*Yeah I know, I should avoid mutating props cause of [One-Way Data Flow](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow).

Comment: **1.** for props=tree, selected, node etc, make an copy to data property instead. **2.** when save tree, emit(one event) to parent component, then assign new value to parent data property)

Comment: Yeah I tried to do this way at start, but that didn't work. Emit one event with what, with this particular node name? How do I find this node and select in 'new tree'?